# Segmentation error when running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I upgraded Android Studio and immediately started having issues building related to Gradle.

I currently have this in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

And in my `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
```

When I try to build I get this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000018 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
Handler1=000000000910B340 Handler2=0000000008EA2C80 InaccessibleAddress=0000000000000000
RDI=000000000F3DCC00 RSI=0000000000000000 RAX=0000000000000404 RBX=0000000000000000
RCX=0000000000000410 RDX=0000000000000000 R8=0000000000000000 R9=00000000006D7BE7
R10=00007F7BA603F578 R11=0000000008D1FC5C R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000
R14=000000000F3DCC00 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=0000000009113DE0 GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=0000700006FE4260
RFlags=0000000000010246 CS=002B RBP=0000700006FE4300 ERR=0000000000000004
TRAPNO=000000040000000E CPU=0000000000040000 FAULTVADDR=0000000000000000
XMM0 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM1 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM2 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM3 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM4 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM5 0000ffffffffffff (f: 4294967296.000000, d: 1.390671e-309)
XMM6 3fa77458f632dcfc (f: 4130528512.000000, d: 4.580954e-02)
XMM7 402a56ef8ec924cc (f: 2395546880.000000, d: 1.316980e+01)
XMM8 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM9 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM10 0000000000000006 (f: 6.000000, d: 2.964394e-323)
XMM11 0000000000000008 (f: 8.000000, d: 3.952525e-323)
XMM12 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM13 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM14 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
XMM15 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
Module=/Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openj9-15.0.1/Contents/Home/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.dylib
Module_base_address=0000000009076000 Symbol=_ZL18getMethodOrFieldIDP7JNIEnv_P7_jclassPKcS4_m
Symbol_address=0000000009113D00
Target=2_90_20201024_81 (Mac OS X 10.16)
CPU=amd64 (12 logical CPUs) (0x400000000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "gpf", detail "" at 2021/12/31 00:27:34 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using '/Users/user/appname/android/core.20211231.002734.137.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP012E Error in System dump: The core file created by child process with pid = 145 was not found. Expected to find core file with name "/cores/core.145"
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/Users/user/appname/android/javacore.20211231.002734.137.0002.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /Users/user/appname/android/javacore.20211231.002734.137.0002.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/user/appname/android/Snap.20211231.002734.137.0003.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /Users/user/appname/android/Snap.20211231.002734.137.0003.trc
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested JIT dump using '/Users/user/appname/android/jitdump.20211231.002734.137.0004.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I JIT dump written to /Users/user/appname/android/jitdump.20211231.002734.137.0004.dmp
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "gpf", detail "".
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 255
```

Comment: How much Ram and ROM you have allotted to your VM?

Comment: @SaraFuerst I think reading [this](https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/9710) might help